# move/copy AWS RDS manual snapshot( postgres) to AWS s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

How can we save AWS RDS manual snapshots on the s3 bucket(on the same account)?
Is Aws will charge for automated RDS snapshots?

Do you guys have a solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> How can we save AWS RDS manual snapshots on the s3 bucket(on the same
>   account)?

You cannot. AWS does not provide access to the raw data of snapshots.

> Is Aws will charge for automated RDS snapshots?

Yes, AWS charges for the storage space that snapshots use.

Answer (score 0):

RDS snapshots are only accessible through the RDS console / CLI.

If you want to export data to your own S3 bucket, you'll need to grab that information directly from the database instance. Something like a `mysqldump`, etc

If you use automated snapshots then AWS will charge you for those.

This is a script i've used in the past to backup a MySQL/Aurora RDS to an S3 bucket:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -o errexit
set -o pipefail
set -o nounset

function log {
  echo "[`date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%N'`] $1"
}

: ${MYSQL_USER:=root}
: ${MYSQL_PASS:=root}
: ${MYSQL_HOST:=127.0.0.1}
: ${MYSQL_PORT:=3306}

if [ -z "${AWS_S3_BUCKET-}" ]; then
    log "The AWS_S3_BUCKET variable is empty or not set"
    exit 1;
fi;

EXCLUDED_DATABASES=(Database information_schema mysql performance_schema sys tmp innodb)

YEAR=$(date '+%Y')
MONTH=$(date '+%m')
DAY=$(date '+%d')
TIME=$(date '+%H-%M-%S')

if [ -z "${MYSQL_DATABASE-}" ]; then
    DATABASES=$(/usr/bin/mysql --host="$MYSQL_HOST" --port="$MYSQL_PORT" --user="$MYSQL_USER" --password="$MYSQL_PASS" -e "SHOW DATABASES;" | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
else
    DATABASES=("$MYSQL_DATABASE")
fi;

for DATABASE in $DATABASES; do

  for EXCLUDED in ${EXCLUDED_DATABASES[@]}; do
    if [ "$DATABASE" == "$EXCLUDED" ]; then
      log "Excluded mysqlbackup of $DATABASE"
      continue 2
    fi;
  done

  log "Starting mysqlbackup of $DATABASE"

  AWS_S3_PATH="s3://$AWS_S3_BUCKET/path-to-folder/$DATABASE.sql.gz"

  mysqldump --host="$MYSQL_HOST" --port="$MYSQL_PORT" --user="$MYSQL_USER" --password="$MYSQL_PASS" "$DATABASE" | gzip | AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY aws s3 cp - "$AWS_S3_PATH"

  log "Completed mysqlbackup of $DATABASE to $AWS_S3_PATH"

done
```